# Javascript- Sync to Outlook

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, dll

I am upgrading an application to use newer browsers which was earlier built for IE 8. The application provides functionality to sync a Distribution List to Contacts folder in outlook and this is being done through javascript.
The code written in javascript is not working in firefox, chrome browsers
The code is

```
SyncToOutlook.BindDataToOutlookFolderCombo = function() {
    var data = document.getElementById('SyncToOutlook_OutlookUtility').GetAllContactFolder();
    SyncToOutlook.storeOutlookFolder.removeAll();
```

The method call GetAllContactFolder is not recognized in and firefox and chrome though it works fine in IE.
The element used here-"SyncToOutlook_OutlookUtility" has a classId= "OutlookClientV6.dll#OutlookClientV6.OutlookUtility". They have added a dll to this project "OutlookClientV6.dll" which is not in references folder.

When the javascript tries to use any of the methods of this dll in firefox or chrome it can't recognize the function though there is no problem in IE.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your Outlook Utility is an ActiveX and unfortunately, ActiveX is not natively supported in both Firefox and Chrome

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/ActiveX

There are workarounds to enable ActiveX controls and get the required functionality based on ActiveX controls.

Chrome users can use the IE Tab extension that emulates IE. 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en-US

Firefox users can try installing ff-activex-host plugin. http://code.google.com/p/ff-activex-host/

These workarounds are not ideal and tedious especially if it needs to be installed to a number of users. Also, a word of caution, there is a risk in using outdated ActiveX controls http://www.microsoft.com/security/pc-security/activex.aspx